# Joomla - VPS - Недостаточно прав для создания файла configuration.php

Tags: cms, joomla, vps

я не знаю как мне решить проблему, мне всегда высвечивает это когда хочу установить эту CMS [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сначала узнал от какого пользователя запущен веб-сервер.

Подробнее здесь: [узнать пользователя](https://unlix.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1/)

Если вкратце, то надо создать php-файл с исполняемым кодом:

```
<?php echo exec('id'); ?>
```

У меня вывод был такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем для этого пользователя выдал права на директорию joomla:

```
chown -R apache:apache <JOOMLA_DIR>
```

В моём случае было так:

```
chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/nginx/html/joomla
```

В большинстве туториалов директорию joomla располагают в:

```
/var/www/html/
```

Это сработало ‍♂️

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]